# Как получать значения через input

Tags: dart

Как записать значение, введенное из клавиатуры в переменную в dart
Например в питоне это реализовано просто: txt = input() вот напрмиер
А как такое делать в dart?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать [readLineSync](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-io/Stdin/readLineSync.html), но работа с консолью возможна только при запуске из командной строки (не работает на [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?null_safety=true))

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print('Введите X:');
  var x = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync() ?? '0');
  print('Введите Y:');
  var y = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync() ?? '0');
  print('Результат X + Y = ${x + y}');
}
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку
type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
  var y = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());

Comment: @lllymka подправил для новой версии, сигнатура метода изменилась.

Comment: Хорошо, Спасибо)